# Ajax request in Ajax request, after 2nd request return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

I currently am using 2 ajax requests in one. After I activate the first request everything shows up. After that in the content that shows up, I can do another ajax request. It is succesfull (can see changes in db).

Now my example is with timers. I open the content from an item through the first request, then there is a timer available for that item. After I click the 2nd request, I notice the timer has started timing. Now when I want to end the timer, I first have to refresh and do those steps again.

How can I return to the second request? I guess with a function, but I don't know how.

Here's the jQuery ajax request:

```
$(".timer").click(function() {

    var project = $(this).attr("data-pid");
    var level = $(this).attr("data-level");
    var global = $(this).attr("data-gid");

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: 'assets/ajax/open-timer.php',
        data: { 'project': project, 'level': level, 'global': global },
        success: function (data) {

            $(".timer-results").html(data);

            $(".start-timer").click(function() {

                var project = $(this).attr("data-pid");
                var level = $(this).attr("data-level");
                var global = $(this).attr("data-gid");

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'assets/ajax/start-timer.php',
                    data: { 'project': project, 'level': level, 'global': global },
                    success: function (data) {

                        $(".timer-to-start").hide();
                        $(".timer-to-stop").show();

                    }

                });

            });

            $(".stop-timer").click(function() {

                var project = $(this).attr("data-pid");
                var level = $(this).attr("data-level");
                var global = $(this).attr("data-gid");

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'assets/ajax/stop-timer.php',
                    data: { 'project': project, 'level': level, 'global': global },
                    success: function (data) {

                        $(".timer-to-stop").hide();
                        $(".timer-to-start").show();

                    }

                });

            });

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Side note: I'm not sure you can use `global` as a variable name in JS. TBC. I don't fully understand your problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a list of tasks. When i click a task I open the task with an ajax request. When the task opens, there is also a timer available. When clicked it should start counting. (All works fine till here)
After it started counting, I want to deactivate the counter by clicking again, but that doesn't work, as I fully ran the ajax request. To stop the timer, i first have to open the task again, and then click the timer to stop. If i want to restart it - again it won't work as I'm throught the whole request. Then i should restart it by opening the task again. And so on... Hope it's clearer now! Thx